# Unittest structure in separate folders in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I want ask you if anyone have idea how to handle problem to run all tests when each of test is in separated folder. And all of them are using same scripts for input file generator. 
What I want to achieve is to have folder structure like this:

```
| - factory.py -> script to generate input data
| - test1 (folder)
|    | - test_case.py
|    | - test.txt
| - test2 (folder)
|    | - test_case.py
|    | - test.txt
```

example of test_case.py:

```
from factory import FileGenerator

class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    #(some code)

    def test_dict(self):
        self.assertDictEqual(self.test, self.json, 'Message')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Right now I am running all test one by one manually. Anyone have idea how to automate this to run all tests from each folder (test1,test2, ...) and see result if it was Pass or Fail??

I was trying to do that with testsuite but I need to keep all tests in different folders. 
Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the python docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

```
python -m unittest discover -s project_directory -p "test_case.py"
```